# To do list app on HTML CSS and Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

I have a project of creating a to-do list application on HTML CSS and Vanilla JavaScript.
I want this list to be able to do these things :

1. User interface for adding and removing tasks
2. Checkbox for marking tasks as complete.
3. Ability to sort tasks by date added, date due, and completion status.
4. Option to add reminders for tasks.
5. Option to categorize tasks into different lists or labels.
6. Persistent storage of tasks using Local Storage. ( Optional )

I managed by searching here and there to complete 1,2,5 and 6 but I'm stuck with 3 and 4

Please note that I am self taught and I only have been learning JavaScript for one month

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')) || [];
  const nameInput = document.querySelector('#name');
  const newTodoForm = document.querySelector('#new-todo-form');

  const username = localStorage.getItem('username') || '';

  nameInput.value = username;

  nameInput.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    localStorage.setItem('username', e.target.value);
  })

  newTodoForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const todo = {
      content: e.target.elements.content.value,
      category: e.target.elements.category.value,
      done: false,
      createdAt: new Date().getTime()
    }

    todos.push(todo);
    sorted_todos = todos.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.createdAt - a.createdAt
    });

    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));

    // Reset the form
    e.target.reset();

    DisplayTodos()
  })

  DisplayTodos()

})

function DisplayTodos() {
  const todoList = document.querySelector('#todo-list');
  todoList.innerHTML = "";

  todos.forEach(todo => {
    const todoItem = document.createElement('div');
    todoItem.classList.add('todo-item');

    const label = document.createElement('label');
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    const content = document.createElement('div');
    const actions = document.createElement('div');
    const edit = document.createElement('button');
    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');

    input.type = 'checkbox';
    input.checked = todo.done;
    span.classList.add('bubble');
    if (todo.category == 'personal') {
      span.classList.add('personal');
    } else {
      span.classList.add('business');
    }
    content.classList.add('todo-content');
    actions.classList.add('actions');
    edit.classList.add('edit');
    deleteButton.classList.add('delete');

    content.innerHTML = `<input type="text" value="${todo.content}" readonly>`;
    edit.innerHTML = 'Edit';
    deleteButton.innerHTML = 'Delete';

    label.appendChild(input);
    label.appendChild(span);
    actions.appendChild(edit);
    actions.appendChild(deleteButton);
    todoItem.appendChild(label);
    todoItem.appendChild(content);
    todoItem.appendChild(actions);

    todoList.appendChild(todoItem);

    if (todo.done) {
      todoItem.classList.add('done');
    }

    input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
      todo.done = e.target.checked;
      localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));

      if (todo.done) {
        todoItem.classList.add('done');
      } else {
        todoItem.classList.remove('done');
      }

      DisplayTodos()

    })

    edit.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      const input = content.querySelector('input');
      input.removeAttribute('readonly');
      input.focus();
      input.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
        input.setAttribute('readonly', true);
        todo.content = e.target.value;
        localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
        DisplayTodos()

      })
    })

    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      todos = todos.filter(t => t != todo);
      localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
      DisplayTodos()
    })

  })
}
```

```css
:root {
  --primary: #EA40A4;
  --others: #3a82ee;
  --personal: var(--primary);
  --light: #EEE;
  --grey: #888;
  --dark: #313154;
  --danger: #ff5b57;
  --shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  --others-glow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(58, 130, 238, 0.75);
  --personal-glow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(234, 64, 164, 0.75);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'montserrat', sans-serif;
}

input:not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]),
button {
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: initial;
}


/* End of Resets */

body {
  background: var(--light);
  color: var(--dark);
}

section {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
}

h3 {
  color: var(--dark);
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

h4 {
  color: var(--grey);
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.greeting .title {
  display: flex;
}

.greeting .title input {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  min-width: 0;
}

.greeting .title,
.greeting .title input {
  color: var(--dark);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.create-todo input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  color: var(--dark);
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: var(--shadow);
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.create-todo .options {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.create-todo .options label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  box-shadow: var(--shadow);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.bubble {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  border: 2px solid var(--others);
  box-shadow: var(--others-glow);
}

.bubble.personal {
  border-color: var(--personal);
  box-shadow: var(--personal-glow);
}

.bubble::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: var(--others);
  box-shadow: var(--others-glow);
  border-radius: 999px;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.bubble.personal::after {
  background-color: var(--personal);
  box-shadow: var(--personal-glow);
}

input:checked~.bubble::after {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.create-todo .options label div {
  color: var(--dark);
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.create-todo input[type="submit"] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: var(--primary);
  box-shadow: var(--personal-glow);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.create-todo input[type="submit"]:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.todo-list .list {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.todo-list .todo-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: var(--shadow);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.todo-item label {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.todo-item .todo-content {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}

.todo-item .todo-content input {
  color: var(--dark);
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

.todo-item .actions {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.todo-item .actions button {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.todo-item .actions button:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.todo-item .actions .edit {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  background-color: var(--primary);
}

.todo-item .actions .delete {
  background-color: var(--danger);
}

.todo-item.done .todo-content input {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: var(--grey);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;0,900;1,400&family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;0,900;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<main class="app">
  <section class="greeting">
    <h2 class="title">
      Hello, <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name here" />
    </h2>
  </section>
  <section class="create-todo">
    <h3>Create A To-Do</h3>
    <form id="new-todo-form">
      <h4>What's on your list?</h4>
      <input type="text" placeholder="e.g. Get some milk" name="content" id="content" />

      <h4>Pick a category</h4>
      <div class="options">
        <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="category" id="category1" value="others" /> 
                        <span class="bubble business"></span>
                        <div>Others</div>
                    </label>
        <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="category" id="category2" value="personal" />
                        <span class="bubble personal"></span>
                        <div>Personal</div>
                    </label>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" value="Add todo" />
    </form>
  </section>
  <section class="todo-list">
    <h3>TO-DO LIST</h3>
    <div class="list" id="todo-list"></div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: You may want to consider putting your code into a CodeSandbox or similar, as it is currently throwing errors when run in StackOverflow, and your form submit is causing a page refresh that melts everything down.  Alternatively, you can fix the errors and prevent the default form submission action, but right now your UI doesn't really work so it's difficult to help you with your issues.

Comment: I have a project of creating a to-do list application on HTML CSS and Vanilla JavaScript. I want this list to be able to do these things :

User interface for adding and removing tasks
Checkbox for marking tasks as complete.
Ability to sort tasks by date added, date due, and completion status.
Option to add reminders for tasks.
Option to categorize tasks into different lists or labels.
Persistent storage of tasks using Local Storage. ( Optional )
I managed by searching here and there to complete 1,2,5 and 6 but I'm stuck with 3 and 4

Comment: Its my first time posting here so I don't actually know how this works or what sandbox is

Comment: I am not sure if you are able to see the Javascript part of my code

Comment: No, we can see your code, and we can run it via the "Run code snippet" button, but I'm just letting you know that, as of now, when I run your code, 1) it throws an error related to CORS policy violation for your localStorage functionality, and 2) Whenever I press the "add task" button, your form submit causes a page reload, which isn't playing well with being hosted inside of a StackOverflow page. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/dashboard/recent?workspace=0118372e-2f6c-427b-a373-a92baa726ee1) is an online tool that lets you host code - similar to a StackSnippet, but generally more robust.

Comment: So in order for people to successfully run your code and help you debug it, I am just suggesting that you may want to put it somewhere where it runs successfully.  It's possible that other folks will be willing to copy it all to a JSFiddle, CodeSandbox, etc themselves and try to run it, but this can sometimes be pretty time consuming and generally the expectation is that the person asking the question puts in this time themselves.

Comment: Outside of this, I think you may want to clarify exactly what you mean for items 3 & 4 - are you familiar with sorting in general and have a specific question related to this problem, or are you looking for a ground-up explanation of how sorting works generally (in JavaScript)?  And what do you mean by reminders?  This could be referring to anything from receiving a text message on your phone to just pushing an alert to your browser, and everything in between.

Comment: I wrote this code in Vscode and it runs and does everything I want, The thing is that In this app when I add a "todo" it goes first on the list so it's kinda like sorted (the latest one goes on top) .As for items 3 and 4 ... Lets forget the item 3. that says : Ability to sort tasks by date added, date due, and completion status. I almost have that in some way

Comment: For item4. I want it actually to push an alert on the console that says like "You still haven't completed this task or something like that (if you have a better idea I'm willing to hear it)   The app saves everything in the local storage according to the user that uses it . So when a user opens up his todo list I want an alert lets say to pop up that says "you still have tasks to do " or "you have 2 remaining tasks to do something like that.....I hope I gave a good explanation (sorry for my English it is not my native language)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-haslett-bp16ks?file=/main.js  I don't now if I did this write but I created an account on codeSandbox and I put my code there

Comment: Good job with the CodeSandbox, looks to be working.  For #4, if all you want to do is push a message to the dev console, then you can use the `console.log` API.  For example, at the top of your code, around line 3, right after you load your todos out of local storage, you can say something like `if (todos && todos.length > 0) {console.log("You have " + todos.length + " tasks still remaining");}`.  Then if you press F12 in your browser and go to the `console` tab, you'll be able to see this message logged.

Comment: If you want it as a native browser alert instead, just replace `console.log` with `alert`; this will be more visible to your average end user (but is generally kind of ugly/not very user friendly).  Even better than this might be to show a custom HTML popup in the middle of the screen, which you could then style and make it look nice etc etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer it was really helpful... I have one question what do you mean by "might be to show a custom HTML popup in the middle of the screen, which you could then style and make it look nice etc etc. " .... Like I can create a specific div for the alert , style it with CSS and then create a function so it would pop up when there are "todo" left to do ?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  You can either just have the div present all the time, and hide it and show it with CSS `display: none`, OR generate it on the fly and append to your document, ala `var popup = document.createElement("div");  // put your custom content and styles in the div;  document.body.appendChild(popup);` (or something similar; this is just a quick example).  And then of course you will have to destroy it (`popup.remove()`) or hide it later after the user acknowledges the alert or something.

Comment: Great, Thank you I will try to do my best and make this work, Thank you so much for your help